# Gitlab CI get commit SHA from main while in another branch

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to get the commit SHA from the main branch while being in another branch? I know that there is a predefined variable for Merge Request but I need it outside of the Merge Request.

Example:

```
-- commit1 -- commit2 -- commit3 [main]
      \
        ----- commit4 -- commit5 [new_branch]
```

In the pipeline of [new_branch] I want to get the commit SHA of commit3

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gitlab API to fetch the latest commit on the main branch

```
'curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $<Your personal or project gitlab token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your gitlab project id>/repository/commits?ref_name=main&per_page=1"'
```

This will return a JSON where the "id" field will have the commit SHA

Please remember to replace the "`<Your personal or project gitlab token>`" and "`<your gitlab project id>`" in the above `curl` command with appropriate values for your project.

Answer (score 1):

To view the full 40 character commit hash any branch is currently pointing to:

```
git rev-parse main
```

It many workflows it's common to not have an up-to-date local copy of the branch you're interested in, so a more accurate approach might be:

```
git fetch
git rev-parse origin/main
```